# TikZ: Difficulty Aligning/Rotating Text in State Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am creating my first state diagram in Tikz. It is finished, except for the text alignment.

[image]

As you can see with the code I included here, I cannot figure out how to get the text off of the arrows. Also, the text on the middle arrow would look better if it matched the angle of the arrow. I looked online, but it seems there are many very different ways people like to code their Tikz diagrams. It makes it hard to find a solution that is applicable to what I have.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this! I am just now learning Tikz, and it is pretty overwhelming.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,theorem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}
\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\pdffalse % we are not running PDFLaTeX
\else
\pdfoutput=1 % we are running PDFLaTeX
\pdftrue
\fi
\ifpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fi
\textwidth = 6.5 in
\textheight = 9 in
\oddsidemargin = 0.0 in
\evensidemargin = 0.0 in
\topmargin = 0.0 in
\headheight = 0.0 in
\headsep = 0.0 in
\parskip = 0.2in
\parindent = 0.0in
\ifpdf
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpg, .png}
\else
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .jpg}
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
node distance = 10mm and 30 mm,
inner sep=5pt,
every edge/.append style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=center, font=\small, inner sep=10pt}
]
% nodes
\node[state, initial, accepting] (1) {Init};
\node[state, right= of 1] (2) {read\_LC\_on};
\node[state, right= of 2] (3) {check LC\_on count};
\node[state, below= of 3] (4) {read\_LC\_off};
\node[state, below= of 4] (5) {check LC\_off count};
\node[state, left= of 5] (6) {read\_data};
\node[state, left= of 6] (7) {check\_data};
% arrows
\path (1) edge[bend left, "pos\_edge"] (2)
(2) edge[loop above,"else"] ()
edge[bend left, "data=\‘0\’"] (3)
(3) edge[bend left, "LC\_on counter \“out of range\”"] (1)
edge[bend left, "LC\_on counter \“in range\”"] (4)
(4) edge[loop left,"else"] ()
edge[bend left, "pos\_edge"] (5)
(5) edge["LC\_off counter \“out of range\”"] (1)
edge[bend left, "LC\_off counter \“in range\”"] (6)
(6) edge[bend left, "pos\_edge"] (7)
edge[loop below,"else" '] ()
(7) edge[bend left, "data\_counter /= 31"] (6)
edge[bend left, "data\_counter = 31"] (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{State Diagram for the Remote Controller}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the [`auto` option](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.auto) so that nodes along the paths are set to the left or right of the path. The key `swap` or it's alias `'` can be used to swap the side for single nodes. This will look award for long lines of text, though. Maybe you want to use `align=center` and put ``\\`` at certain places in the node's text to start a new line.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you meant like this below, and I adjusted the head of your code; I'm compiling with Xelatex here.

Hope this will be one of the solutions that fits you well ^.^

You can use `pos` to adjust the relevant position of text and the arrow line (closer to start or closer to end, from 0 to 1), something like this `[pos=.5]`
and set `\path [every node/.style={sloped}]` to make the text's direction consistent with your lines. some of your text here is a bit long that it corrupt into a block, you can try `[below/above/..=xxx pt]` to adjust the distance.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,theorem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\textwidth = 6.5 in
\textheight = 9 in
\oddsidemargin = 0.0 in
\evensidemargin = 0.0 in
\topmargin = 0.0 in
\headheight = 0.0 in
\headsep = 0.0 in
\parskip = 0.2in
\parindent = 0.0in
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpg, .png}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
        node distance = 10mm and 30 mm,
        inner sep=5pt,
        every edge/.append style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
        every edge quotes/.style = {auto=center, font=\small, inner sep=6pt}
        ]
        % nodes
        \node[state, initial, accepting] (1) {Init};
        \node[state, right= of 1] (2) {read\_LC\_on};
        \node[state, right= of 2] (3) {check LC\_on count};
        \node[state, below= of 3] (4) {read\_LC\_off};
        \node[state, below= of 4] (5) {check LC\_off count};
        \node[state, left= of 5] (6) {read\_data};
        \node[state, left= of 6] (7) {check\_data};
        % arrows
        \path [every node/.style={sloped,above}]
        (1) edge[bend left] node {pos\_edge} (2)
        (2) edge[loop above] node {else} ()
        edge[bend left] node {data=0} (3)
        (3) edge[bend left] node [pos=.3,below]{LC\_on counter out of range} (1)
        edge[bend left] node [below=14pt,pos=.4]{LC\_on counter in range} (4)
        (4) edge[loop left] node [pos=.8]{else} ()
        edge[bend left] node {pos\_edge} (5)
        (5) edge node [pos=.3]{LC\_off counter out of range} (1)
        edge[bend left] node [below,pos=.4]{LC\_off counter in range} (6)
        (6) edge[bend left] node [below]{pos\_edge}(7)
        edge[loop below] node [below]{else} ()
        (7) edge[bend left] node {data\_counter /= 31} (6)
        edge[bend left] node {data\_counter = 31} (1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{State Diagram for the Remote Controller}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Besides, for more information, you can check these questions:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45055/286140
- [How to place label in middle of line (above and below) with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96846/286140)